# How do I open and modify OpenCascade files?

Tags: python, opencascade

I need to open and modify a file (cnc program) that is in the OpenCascade format.
How do I do this? Any libraries available for Python?

I tried treating it as an .xml file but this did not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document format="MPRxOcaf" xmlns="http://www.opencascade.org/OCAF/XML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opencascade.org/OCAF/XML">
 <info date="2019-09-13" schemav="0" DocVersion="7" objnb="583">
  <iitem>Copyright: Open Cascade, 2001-2002</iitem>
  <iitem>REFERENCE_COUNTER: 0</iitem>
```

Comment: Have you checked http://www.pythonocc.org/?

Comment: Best wrapper I've found so far: https://github.com/CadQuery/OCP and here you have useful resources to build: https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=python-ocp

Answer (score 0):

Quoted fragment is not exactly "OpenCascade format". Open CASCADE Technology (OCCT) comes with **Application Framework** module defining **OCAF** document (stands for 'Open CASCADE Application Framework'), which is a low-level data API defining an **arbitrary document**. It also implements routines for reading/writing documents in binary (**BinOcaf**) and Xml (**XmlOcaf**) formats.

OCCT has also **XCAF** document relying on OCAF, which defines an assembly structure of shapes with attributes (colors, names, locations) and has binary (**BinXCAF**) and Xml (**XmlXCAF**) storage formats. XCAF documents are used for importing and exporting files in STEP / IGES formats. Binary files usually has .xbf file extension.

The document header in your question defines **MPRxOcaf** format based on OCAF. Such format does not exist in OCCT, so that it should be invented by **specific application**. The knowledge that it is based on OCAF will barely help here. Reading this document without documentation from application authors will require *reverse-engineering* to understand its structure. To read it back into OCCT-based application, it will be necessary defining necessary OCAF plugins and drivers decoding entities - could be pretty much of work for a complex document structure.